# is it possible to integrate Eye-Fi into iPad/iPhone application?

Tags: ios

[Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi) is an SD card with built-in WiFi module - so images from the digital camera can be transmitted directly to iPad. But - you must have their app installed and running. I'm wondering if it's possible to integrate this functionality (receive images from WiFi card) into my iOS application. Does anybody have any experience - positive or negative - with this? Any links please? I googled but I was not able to find a clear answer.

Thank you.

Comment: I've never used Eye-Fi, but I see there might be a possibility for you [if you reach out to them via their Developer Program](http://www.eye.fi/developer).

Comment: thanks - I assume it's a lengthy process and I just wanted to get a confirmation from SO users before I go that way. Eventually I will.

Answer (score 1):

I've been hopeful of Eye-Fi launching an API for 3rd party mobile apps to integrate directly with the Eye-Fi card in some capacity.

In a nutshell there isn't currently an Eye-Fi API/SDK, but rather Eye-Fi is encouraging developers to integrate with their [Circ](http://www.getcirc.com/) product via it's [official developer program](https://dev.getcirc.com/).

---

Here's a more verbose timeline covering news and developments around an Eye-Fi API/SDK up to Apr 2013:

Eye-Fi had originally [launched a developer program](http://mashable.com/2010/09/07/eye-fi-developer-program/) back in 2010. All links on the Eye-Fi site regarding the program, however, are now dead.

The Eye-Fi forums then served as a somewhat [ad-hoc waiting list](http://forums.eye.fi/viewtopic.php?t=6958) in late 2012/early 2013 to get into the next incarnation of the developer program.

This basically ended with the [announcement of the Circ developer program](http://forums.eye.fi/viewtopic.php?t=6958#p28158):

> While you are here due to interest in an Eye-Fi API, we would like to let you know that we here at Eye-Fi have developed a new cloud based product currently in beta called Circ which includes a new public API and SDK based. [...] Much of what was requested by people like you interested in an Eye-Fi API has been included in Circ.

The Circ developer program is here: https://dev.getcirc.com/

Comment: This is a great answer but I don't see how connecting to the Circ cloud is feasible for those that are wanting to write apps to use an EyeFi card in Direct mode with an iOS device hooked only into the EyeFi card WiFi...

Comment: aaaaaaand the circ links are dead.  I'm detecting a pattern here. :\

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. I've done it. Start here: https://github.com/Ignigena/PhotoPad

Answer (score 0):

The last I heard from EyeFi on this matter was back in 2011 - they noted that the EyeFi app would keep writing photos to the photo library for ten minutes after it was backgrounded.

Comment: I went looking but could not find original post either - I removed the dead link so as not to confuse anyone else.  Sorry.  :-(